# How to get CSS Background Colour with Python?

Tags: python, html, css, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

Basically exactly as the question says, I'm trying to get the background colour out from a website.

At the moment I'm using `BeautifulSoup` to get the `HTML`, but it's proving a difficult way of the getting the `CSS`. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not something you can reliably solve with `BeautifulSoup`. You need **a real browser**.

The simplest option would be to use [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) browser automation tool:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('url')

element = driver.find_element_by_id('myid')
print(element.value_of_css_property('background-color'))
```

[`value_of_css_property()` documentation](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.value_of_css_property).

Comment: Is it still the case as of today? can't BeautifulSoup do that yet?